# Why is lambda over np.fromfunction returning scalar

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

Following is the python code which I expect to return a vector but returns a scalar. Why is lambda with np.fromfunction not working as expected in this case?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> squarer = lambda t: np.sum(b)
>>> a = np.fromfunction(squarer, (3,), dtype=int)
>>> a
6
```

Specifically in my case below is the actual code which is returning scalar. trx and tray are arrays.

```
>>>exp = lambda j: np.sum(np.fromfunction(lambda i: alpha[i] *\
  (1 + trx[i]*tray[j])**pow, (size,), dtype=int))
>>>a = np.fromfunction(exp, (tray.shape[0], ), dtype=int)
>>>a
1545
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about `np.fromfunction`. It's not applying a function element-wise to a provided array. It computes a function across each *dimension* of an index array of the provided shape. I.e., `t` is not a scalar, but, for each dimension in the input shape, it is the array which indexes that whole axis.